# class inheritance design pattern (Python)

Tags: python, class, inheritance

In Python, I've extended the functionality of a third party class `Base1` by subclassing it as `MyBase1(Base1)`. Now there are two other classes `Base2` and `Base3` which are very similar. In fact all base classes inherit from the `Base` class with very minor differences, essentially a single argument set to `1, 2 3` respectively.

I want to extend the other ones into `MyBase2` and `MyBase3` as well, and the differences between the 3 is similarly small as in the original classes. A complication is that the `Base` class itself is not public, only the 3 child classes are.

Simply subclassing `MyBase2(Base2)` and `MyBase3(Base3)` would work, but would lead to 3 copies of almost identical code, up to a few lines.

So the question is how to do this elegantly, minimizing code duplication and maximizing modularity. Note that the added functionality changes the base classes in a way that can't be achieved by simply making the class `Base1` an attribute of the class `MyBase1`.

I only have experience with basic class inheritance, is there a pattern suited for this?

Comment: _In fact all base classes inherit from the Base class with very minor differences, essentially a single argument set to 1, 2 3 respectively_ - why would you want/have 3 classes for that in the first place? Maybe if you can show some code.

Comment: What do you mean that the `Base` class is not public? There is no such thing as public/private in Python.

Comment: Also try not to name your classes as too generic, like `Base1`, `Base2`, etc. If they each perform specific functionality, like reading files for example, I’d name them something like `FileReader`. ideally all classes should each perform a specific functionality, and if you need other functionality you can as mentioned add a new class for that.

Comment: Can you not just pass the argument set to 1,2 and 3 to the constructor ? Why build 3 classes ?

Comment: @buran That's in the third party code, whose conventions I want to follow. Specifically with `Base` I'm referring to the `Conv` class in Keras, a deep learning framework, and with `Base1` etc to `Conv1D` etc. The number refers to the amount of spatial dimensions, and this convention I suppose is because in a typical use case, this is fixed (most commonly 2).

Comment: @rv.kvetch I mean that the third party code designates this as private, I suppose meaning that there's no guarantee the interface will stay the same in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to add the behavior you want with dependency injection, or by having the base be a member of your class passed in the constructor (favor composition over inheritance)?

Comment: It depends on your use case: How will MyBase2 be different (in behaviour or structure) from Base2?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn Not sure what you're asking, MyBase1,2,3 will differ in the same way as Base,1,2,3 do, i.e. in a way that can be encapsulated in a single argument taking the corresponding value 1,2,3. And MyBase2 overrides some methods of Base2, essentially doing some preprocessing, calling the parent method and some postprocessing.

Comment: @KennyOstrom If there's no better way I think I can make it work by having a MyBase class that doesn't subclass anything but sets a base attribute to either Base1, Base2 or Base3 depending on an argument, and then subclass that into MyBase1 etc. But I would like MyBase1's interface to be as close as possible to Base1's, while this approach would require interjecting a `base` in all method calls, i.e. `my_base_1.base.base_method()`.